# New to python, i need to plot a bar chart from the output which is in percentages

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I used the below code to filter out the top 5 Items by percentages in the DataFrame

```
df = df['Country'].value_counts(normalize=True).mul(100).round(2).astype(str) +'%' 
df.head(5)
```

Output

```
United States     32.78%
India              8.79%
France             4.75%
United Kingdom     4.35%
Germany            3.96%

Name: Country, dtype: object
```

How can I plot the output using a bar graph?

Answer (score 2):

You need to get your percentages back to a  numeric datatype:

```
df.str[:-1].astype(float).plot.bar()
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_clipboard(header=None, sep=r"[ ]{2,}", names=['country', 'percent'])
df['percent'] = df['percent'].astype(str).str.strip('%')
df['percent'] = pd.to_numeric(df['percent'])
df.set_index('country', inplace=True)
df.plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]